# Filter duplicates based on condition in another column

Tags: r

I would like to filter my data frame to remove duplicated IDs in "Gene" and keep only the one with lowest "Pval". Please see my example:

in

```
Gene Pval
buc  0.01
buc  0.3
abad 0.0002
abad 0.01
myc  0.1
p53  0.03
```

out

```
Gene Pval
buc  0.01
abad 0.0002
myc  0.1
p53  0.03
```

Comment: what is the criteria with which you pick the Pval out of the possible options, eg. for gene puc 0.01 vs 0.3? looks like you need something like `dplyr::group_by(df, Gene) %>% dplyr::summarise(Pval = min(Pval, na.rm = T)) %>% dplyr::ungroup()`

Comment: Look up all Pval for gene buc and keep the smallest

Comment: Not sure why `adad` is filtered out.

Comment: @NelsonGon, Typo, corrected now

Answer (score 1):

We can use:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  filter(Pval==min(Pval)) %>% 
  unique()
```